# Is opening a dropdown after clearing it a good practice?

Tags: dropdown

Currently in our application we have a dropdown that opens again directly after getting cleared. I imagine this can be handy for some users, but annoying for others. Is this a good practice to follow?

[image]

Context: This is being used in combination with other dropdowns that all act as filters. A list will get limited or extended based on the values (or when they're empty) in those dropdowns.

Comment: I don't see any problem with this. If you clear it, it's most likely because you want to enter/choose something else. In that case, opening it immediately comes in handy in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is dropdown necessary field? If so, reopening it could be good choice. If its not - in that context I don't see additional click that would re toggle it again as much annoying for user, as mouse is already there.

Comment: It's not a necessary field, it is a filter that filters down a large list of items

Comment: You can ask yourself; How likely is that someone with clicking on X icon, wants to stop doing filtering versus how likely is that he wants to reset filter. As mentioned, if its not obligatory, additional click someone needs to invest in toggling filter again is not so "expensive".

Comment: Mouseflow recordings or Analytics Click event tracking can help you to get data on behavior over time, which can be then ground for decission also

Answer (score 3):

You are generous to think about your users, @Gerlof. But it is NOT good practice to surprise the user. No matter if the surprise is good or bad – it is still a shock to the psyche and causes a moment of hesitation. Hesitation may add to the user time and plants doubt in their ability to navigate.

If a user clicks on an X, they are expecting the field to clear. If they wish to click on the caret, they expect the dropdown to trigger. Stick to the universal rules that 99% of users expect.

Saving your user a click is not your goal. Deliver their expectation and simply let the X be a 'CLEAR THE FIELD' only.